# How to take the next indexPath in a uiTableviewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I want to fill up my custom tableview cells with 5 different imageviews.
In my customTableViewCell I do this.

```
-(void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forPosition:(NSUInteger)position{
    if(position == 1){
        _img_Player1.image = image;
    }else if(position == 2){
        _img_Player2.image = image;
    }else if(position == 3){
        _img_Player3.image = image;
    }else if(position == 4){
        _img_Player4.image = image;
    }else if(position == 5){
        _img_Player5.image = image;
    }else if(position == 6){
        _img_Player6.image = image;
    }

}
```

And in my CellForRowAtIndexPath I do this.

```
   static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"PlayerCustomCell";

    PlayerCustomCell *cell = (PlayerCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PlayerCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    Team *team = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSData* imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:team.image]];
    UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
    for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)
    {
        [cell setImage:image forPosition:i];

    }


    return cell;
```

At the moment my tableview looks like this.

```
|---------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                                                     |
|    bird image   bird image   bird image     bird image  bird image  |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                                                     |
|   dog image    dog image    dog image    dog image   dog image      |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                                                     |
|  cat image     cat image    cat image    cat image     cat image    |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

I hope you see what the problem is. I think that after it sets the image it should go to the next indexPath. My question is now how can I do this ?

kind regards.

Comment: One problem is that you're calling `setImage:forPosition:` with the values 0-to-5 but it attempts to deal with 1-to-6.  Other than that, how do you want your table to look?

Comment: here is a screenshot of what I want to achieve http://www.flickr.com/photos/74322780@N08/8050170687/

Comment: From that, it seems that `Team` needs to have an array of five URL strings, one for each position.  Then, inside your loop, you would create a different image for each index.

Comment: I think you should accept some answers before asking new questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly add 5 NSData like this in .h file

```
  NSData *birdImgData;
  NSData *dogImgData;
  NSData *catImgData;
  NSData *aImgData;
  NSData *bImgData;
```

In CellForRowAtIndexPath do this:

```
 static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"PlayerCustomCell";

PlayerCustomCell *cell = (PlayerCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PlayerCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

if(indexPath.row == 0){

Team *team = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if(!birdImgData){
   birdImgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL 
URLWithString:team.image]];
   UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:birdImgData];
   [cell setImage:image forPosition:1];
}

NSIndexPath *path1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row+1 inSection:0];
Team *team1 = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:path1];
if(!dogImgData){
    dogImgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:team1.image]];
   UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:dogImgData];
   [cell setImage:image forPosition:2];
}

NSIndexPath *path2 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row+2 inSection:0];
Team *team2 = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:path2];
if(!catImgData){
   catImgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:team2.image]];
   UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:catImgData];
   [cell setImage:image forPosition:3];
}

NSIndexPath *path3 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row+3 inSection:0];
Team *team3 = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:path3];
if(!aImgData){
   aImgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:team3.image]];
   UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:aimageData];
   [cell setImage:image forPosition:4];
}

NSIndexPath *path4 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row+4 inSection:0];
Team *team4 = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:ipath4];
if(!bImgData){
   bImgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:team4.image]];
   UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:bimageData];
   [cell setImage:image forPosition:5];
}
}
else
{
  if(birdImgData){
    UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:birdImgData];
   [cell setImage:image forPosition:1];
  }
  if(dogImgData){
    UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:dogImgData];
   [cell setImage:image forPosition:2];
  }
  if(catImgData){
    UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:catImgData];
   [cell setImage:image forPosition:3];
  }
  if(aImgData){
    UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:aImgData];
   [cell setImage:image forPosition:4];
  }
  if(bImgData){
    UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:bimageData];
   [cell setImage:image forPosition:5];
  }
} 

return cell;
```

Comment: The error is the following "Arithmetic on pointer to interface 'NSIndexPath', which is not a constant size in non-fragile ABI

Comment: @StefGeelen This is because an index path is more or less a set. There is a section component and a row component. Try: `indexPath.row + 1`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it needs an indexpath an your solution gives back an int.

Comment: No, but this is also not working, Because it needs an indexPath and this gives back an int.

Comment: Use [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:inSection:] to quickly create an index path.

Comment: Oké thank you this worked. But now it is display on each row the same 6 images. Is it possible to count this further on the next row ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)
{
    [cell setImage:image forPosition:i];

}
```

Sets the same image for each imageView in your cell. This code can be unwinded to something like

```
UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
[cell setImage:image forPosition:0];
[cell setImage:image forPosition:1];
[cell setImage:image forPosition:2];
[cell setImage:image forPosition:3];
[cell setImage:image forPosition:4];
[cell setImage:image forPosition:5];
```

So you get exactly what you are asking for: the same image on each position in the cell. If you want different image in each cell, you need to get six different links for six different player images, then you need to download these images and set each image to proper position in the cell.